# How to make EditText trigger parent view scroll?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

Multiline EditText in a ScrollView. Edittext can scroll if its content overflows. the direction is the same.
How to let EditText trigger ScollView scroll when it can not scroll(hit top bottom or not much content)?

Answer (score 0):

```
 private final void focusOnView(){
    your_scrollview.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            your_scrollview.scrollTo(0, your_EditBox.getBottom());
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: that not what i meant, i mean when you move in the direction on EditText , if EditText can scroll, scroll the EditText, if not scroll the parent.

Comment: so you want if you scroll a page in android,if it contains edit text with scrollable feature then it should scroll otherwise the page should be scrolled right?

Comment: yes, only if the touch starts in EditText @Prashant Jaiswal